# SQL One to Many join getting single result per join

Tags: sql

I want to export data from a SQL 2008 server to a file, csv or excel doesn't matter. In the database I have two entities, questions and answers. The problem is that the questions has multiple answers. A join will then result in multiple rows per each question. How can I do so the result is just one row per question and answers, just adding a new column per each answer. Like this:

Table structure:

```
Question
-------------
Id
Text
Category

Answer
-------------
Id
Text
IsCorrect
QuestionId
```

Example of result:

```
         Col1       Col2           Col3          Col4          Col5          Col6          Col7
Result1: Question1, Question1Text, Answer1Prop1, Answer1Prop2, Answer2Prop1, Answer2Prop2, null
Result2: Question2, Question2Text, Answer3Prop1, Answer3Prop2, Answer4Prop1, Answer4Prop2, Answer5Prop3
```

Comment: Please put me in the right direction instead of down vote...

Comment: Include in your question more detail, table structure specifically.  I would research the type of joins available to you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can produce a result with your joins containing all the questions and all the answers with multiple rows, like you describe, I think you could use a cursor to loop over all the questions and answers, and then have a temptable/"hashtable" (#tableOfAnswers) to hold your final result. For each answer for a question you alter the #table and add a new column.

Something like this might put you in the right direction.

If you have a result looking something like this:
(In my example I've stored the result below in a temp table called "#q")

```
QuestionId  text
1           answer1
1           answer2
1           answer3
1           answer4
2           answer1
2           answer2
```

Then you can declare a cursor on the result

```
Declare @questionId int
, @questionText varchar(max)
, @prevId int
, @colNo int = 1
, @colMax int = 0
, @i int = 1
, @sql nvarchar(max)
, @nulls nvarchar(max) = ''

Create table #tempTable
(
    QuestionId int not null,
    Col1 varchar(max) null
)

Declare question_cursor cursor for
Select QuestionId, text
From #q

Open question_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM question_cursor 
INTO @questionId, @questionText

Set @prevId = 0

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
If (@prevId = @questionId)
Begin
    If (@colNo > @colMax)
    Begin
        Set @sql = N'alter table #tempTable add Col' + cast(@colNo as varchar) + ' varchar(max) null'
        exec sp_executesql @statement = @sql

        Set @colMax = @colMax + 1
    End

    Set @sql = N'update #tempTable set Col' + cast(@colNo as varchar) + ' = ''' + @questionText + ''' where QuestionId = ' + cast(@questionId as varchar)

    print @sql

    exec sp_executesql @statement = @sql
    Set @colNo = @colNo + 1
End
Else Begin
    Set @prevId = @questionId
    Set @colNo = 1

    while (@i <= @colMax)
    begin
        set @nulls = @nulls + ', null'
        set @i = @i + 1
    end

    Set @sql = N'insert into #tempTable values (' + cast(@questionId as varchar) + ', ''' + @questionText + '''' + isnull(@nulls, '') +')'

    print @sql

    exec sp_executesql @statement = @sql
    Set @colNo = @colNo + 1
End 

FETCH NEXT FROM question_cursor 
INTO @questionId, @questionText
END

Close question_cursor
Deallocate question_cursor

Select * from #tempTable
```

That will produce a result like this:

```
QuestionId    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
1             text1   text2   text3   text4
2             text1   text2   NULL    NULL
```

Not quite as elegant as .Net (or javascript even) would handle a problem like this.. But well, what you gonna do? :)
I hope that might shed some light on your problem :)

And for exporting it to a file I would just copy/paste the result in Sql Management Studio and paste it in Excel or something ;)